# compare string with data frame

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I am trying to compare strings with elements inside a dataframe.
My strings in the file are like this:

```
0100000000
0001000000
```

I would like to pass every line from my file to the **position** in dataframe, and if the line corresponds, then print the line and its corresponding **vector** of the dataframe. Something like this:

```
0100000000 01
0001000000 01
```

I have this code so far, it's basic and I don't know how to continue

```
import pandas as pd

data_f = pd.DataFrame(
    {'position':
        {0: '1000000000',
         1: '0100000000',
         2: '0010000000',
         3: '0001000000',
         4: '0000100000',
         5: '0000010000'},
     'vector': {0: '10', 1: '01', 2: '10', 3: '01', 4: '01', 5: '01'}})

with open("/test_2vec/example_vec61.txt", "r") as f1:
    for vec in f1:
        print(vec)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1** (iterative)

Iterate over file's lines and check if a line occurs within a `position` column of the dataframe `df`:

```
with open('yourfile.txt') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        line = line.strip()
        vec = df.loc[df['position'].eq(line.strip()), 'vector'].values
        if vec.size:
            print(line, vec[0])
```

---

**Approach #2**  ([merging](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), the shorter one)

Load the text file with lines to another dataframe to merge it with the initial one on matched lines.

```
df2 = pd.read_table('yourfile.txt', header=None, dtype=str)
matched_df = df.merge(df2, left_on='position', right_on=0)
print(matched_df.to_string(columns=['position', 'vector'], header=None, index=None))
```

The output (for the initial input):

```
0000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000 01
0000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 01
0000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000 01
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100 10
0000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000 10
0000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 10
0000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 01
0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 01
0000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You could read the file into a `set` then get the positions that are elements of it. The only thing is this doesn't preserve the order of the lines.

```
with open(...) as f1:
    pos = set(line.rstrip('\n') for line in f1)

df_out = data_f.loc[data_f['position'].isin(pos)]
df_out
```

```
     position vector
1  0100000000     01
3  0001000000     01
```

Then to print it like you want:

```
print(df_out.to_string(header=False, index=False))
```

```
0100000000 01
0001000000 01
```